# Como poner los requisitos de mi app en el instalador

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

Para crear un Instalador de una aplicación de escritorio utilizo Bases de datos, Crystal Report y algunas librerías para el diseño.

Al momento de correr el instalador en mi pc, el instalador funciona de lo mejor.
Pero al momento de correrlo en otra pc, solo aparece el símbolo de carga y la app no corre pues no presenta la interfaz gráfica.

Me han dicho que eso pasa por los requisitos de la app. Osea, si la app en donde estoy corriendo mi instalador no cumple los requisitos necesarios para correr la app como .Net, Crystal Report o la base de datos, pues esta misma no se ejecutará.

Cómo puedo meter los requisitos de la app en mi instalador para que el cliente no tenga que descargarlo por otra parte?.

Comment: Y como estas haciendo el instalador? ahi es donde deberian estar los requisitos...

Comment: Estoy utilizando un proyecto llamado Setup en Visual Studio, pero es que no se cómo añadir los requisitos del programa. Si tienes algo que me ayude te lo agradecería.

Comment: Setup tiene la opcion de bajar los pre requesitos o de mandarlos con el instalador. Leiste toda la documentacion de ese tipo de proyecto?

Comment: Me leí la docuemtación pero aun asi estaba algo confusa , si me pudieras conseguir algun tipo de documentacion a parte te lo agradecería.

Comment: no. la documentacion es la oficial de la msdn...